# Smtp Config in asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, smtp, google-apps

Hai,
I have developed small asp.net application.i send mail through this application.so my web config file have following coding

```
    <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="username@domainname.com" password="*****"  />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

we have google apps.we don't have mail server.
i try to sent mail,i getting time out error.
regards
mariyappan.J

Comment: You want to send mail through settings of your web.config file or some other alternative

Comment: Have you tried with port="465"

Comment: 587 works for google apps for me

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **System.Net.Mail.MailMessage** try this:

```
yourMailMessage.EnableSsl = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be:

- Firewall related
- IIS User account related
- <del>Have you tried `smtp.googlemail.com`</del> Reading [this](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287) it doesn't matter

I realise that's a bit of a generic answer but your config settings are correct so logically it can only be related to the network, or the user.